# How can i use kubectl labelselector with or contidion?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to get pod with label

app=vovo
component=db

When i get a pod with label app=vovo and component=db, i can get the result with below command.

```
kubectl get pod -l app=vovo,component=db
```

However, when i want to get the result

app=vovo or component=db

How can i get the result with one kubectl command?

Comment: I do not think you can use `or` condition in a single query for `two different labels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OR` operations for label selection is not supported as per the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors)

> Caution: For both equality-based and set-based conditions there is no
> logical OR (||) operator. Ensure your filter statements are structured
> accordingly

Here is a close **hack** you could do:

```
kubectl get pod -l app=volvo && kubectl get pod -l component=db --no-headers
```

This will run two `kubectl` queries for two different labels.